# How to sort out integers and strings from a textfile?

Tags: python, list, sorting

So I'm trying to create a program which reads a text file and outputs the strings and integers in some sortations.

I'd like to print out at which row the strings were at and also create lists with all the integers in the text file. (To further use the integers to find min, max, median etc.)

I've tried and got stuck completely unfortunally.

```
def readfile(file):
    try:
        f = open(file, 'r')
        fil = f.readlines()
        f.close()
        return fil
    except IOError:
        print('fil finns inte')
        return None

def rader(rowlist):
    k=rowlist
    l=[]
    try:
        for i in k:
            l.append(int(i.strip()))
            return l
    except:
        print("sds")
```

So this code is obviously not finished and also is currently run with a doctest. I'm stuck at the part where I want to sort the integers to a list and the strings to print out together with the row number.

So obviously I'd like a loop which goes through a list of the document, when it hits an integer, append it to a list and when it hits an string, stop, just to the except case or something like that, and print the string out together with the number of the row (i).

How do I create this? I'm not looking for a very complicated program, but more a simple loop which I just can't see in my head how to code.

Answer (score 0):

Please see an example:

```
def get_integer_or_none(text):
    '''
    Returns integer from text or None if text is not an integer.
    '''
    try:
        return int(text)
    except ValueError:
        return None

for text in ('1', 'some text', '2 not an integer', '-1000'):
    integer_value = get_integer_or_none(text)
    if integer_value is not None:
        print('This text "{}" is an integer ({})'.format(text, integer_value))
    else:
        print('This text "{}" is not an integer'.format(text))
```

Comment: Thanks, though I don't really understand the second part. Would you care to elaborate?

Comment: Second part is just an example for 4 strings: '1', 'some text', '2 not an integer', '-1000'. It uses function get_interger_or_none() for each string and prints if result is an integer.